# QStylesheet not working after adding widget to layout

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have created a custom widget and applied the following stylesheet to it (via QtDesigner):

```
QWidget#MyWidget{
background: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 
rgb(200, 200, 200), stop:1 rgb(230, 230, 230))
}

QWidget#MyWidget:hover{
background: 
qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #90B750, 
stop:1#CAFF70 )
}
```

It works perfekt in the designer.

In another custom widget, I add a lot of those MyWidget instances to a Vertical layout. But neither the background color is set according to the stylesheet, nor does the hovering work. For testing purposes, I added a pushbutton to MyWidget. Hovering and clicking works. What am I missing?

Basically MyWidget is just a widget with a few labels, the "container" is just a ScrollArea with a vertical layout and again a few labels.

Any ideas?

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, solution is fairly simple.

The problem is, that apparently, if you parent a widget to another widget, the background of the top-most widget is set to "transparent". Adding a second widget which has the main widget as parent and applying the QStylesheet to this widget solves the problem.